# Eclipse kepler hangs showing only the splash screen while starting first time

Tags: 14.04, eclipse

I am using kepler to the ubuntu 14.04 first time. While i start the eclipse it shows the splash screen only and hang on it. How to overcome from this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have similiar problem which resolved using oracle java 1.7 not openjdk and changing ubuntu theme to radiance. Eclipse got some problems with themes under ubuntu

Comment: i am using oracle java 1.7. i don't understand what u mean to change the ubuntu theme to radiance

Comment: some themes is unsupported in eclipse, please run eclipse from terminal and paste error code here

Comment: no error code same thing happen

Comment: Add -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/dev/null to eclipse.ini as per https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776#c22

Comment: ..i add this but nothing change.